# useState for an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having difficulty using the hook useState for objects in React.
I have a button that I was hoping to reuse to clean up my code.

I can use a new function for every instance of the button but I assume there is another way.
Maybe I can restructure my variables, I am somewhat new to this so I am not sure of the best way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProjectVB from "./ProjectVB";
import ProjectBB from "./ProjectBB";
import Up from "../icons/Up.svg";
import Down from "../icons/Down.svg";
import exampleVB from "../icons/projectVB.JPG";
import exampleBB from "../icons/projectBB.jpg";

const Projects = () => {
  const [moreInfo, setMoreInfo] = useState({
    SC: true,
    VF: true,
    VB: true,
    BB: true,
  });
  const [aboutButton, setAboutButton] = useState({
    BB: Down,
    VB: Down,
    SC: Down,
    VF: Down,
  });
  const [project, setProject] = useState({
    SC: false,
    VF: false,
    VB: false,
    BB: false,
  });

  const ContinueReadingFunction = value => {
    setMoreInfo.value(!moreInfo.value)
    if (moreInfo.value === true) {
      setProject.value(!project.value);
      setAboutButton.value(Up);
    } else {
      aboutButton.value = Down;
      project.value = false;
    }
  };


return (
<div className="imageContainer">
          <div className="buttonBox">
            <button
              className="aboutButton"
              onClick={() => ContinueReadingFunction("BB")}
            >
              <img
                src={aboutButton.BB}
                className="logo"
                alt="More or less information."
              />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="exampleImage">
            <img
              src={exampleBB}
              className="exampleImageImage"
              alt="screenshot of the project"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {project.BB && <ProjectBB />}
      </div>
      <div className="projectContainer">
        <h3>Vegan Berlin</h3>
        <div className="imageContainer">
          <div className="buttonBox">
            <button className="aboutButton" onClick={ContinueReadingFunction}>
              <img
                src={aboutButton.VB}
                className="logo"
                alt="More or less information."
              />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="exampleImage">
            <img
              src={exampleVB}
              className="exampleImageImage"
              alt="screenshot of the project"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {project.VB && <ProjectVB />}
      </div>
  );
};
export default Projects;
```

I can use a bunch of separate functions to achieve the results but I am trying to refactor my code to learn the new hooks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple issues in your continue reading function

The useState setter functions just set whatever you pass them as the new state, so you need to pass the whole object again. also it looks like you are trying to subset the values in the objects themselves, to do this you need to use [] notation.

Try this:

```
const ContinueReadingFunction = value => {
  const newMoreInfo = { ...moreInfo }; // copy moreInfo to avoid mutating state
  newMoreInfo[value] = !moreInfo[value];
  setMoreInfo(newMoreInfo);

  const newAboutButton = { ...aboutButton };
  const newProject = { ...project };

  if (newMoreInfo[value]) { // no need to use equality check for truthy values
    newProject[value] = !project[value];
    newAboutButton[value] = Up;
  } else {
    newProject[value] = false;
    newAboutButton[value] = Down;
  }

  setProject(newProject);
  setAboutButton(newAboutButton);
};
```